# Arcane Bonds and Familiars

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

Is it possible for a [Wizard](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/wizard.html#_wizard) to gain both an [arcane bond](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/wizard.html#arcane-bond) and a [familiar](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/wizard.html#familiars) *without* multiclassing?

I have not found a way to do it, but I'm keen to find out if it is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not found anything specific to pathfinder.

However, there is a dnd 3.5 feat that does this:

```
Name: Obtain Familiar 
Book: Complete Arcane 
Short description: Gain a familiar.
```

Complete Arcane, p. 81

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a pathfinder based solution.

Comment: Well; despite best efforts to determine something and bribe people; looks like there isn't a way in PF. So awarding this for those people in 3.5, as the other answer hasn't been verified in the referred to book.

Answer (score 2):

It is now Pathfinder legal too. It was adapted in the conversion of Rise of the Runelords. Requires a rank of knowledge arcana and 3rd caster level

Comment: Might have a better place as a comment, though...

Comment: can you post any references to support your answer?

Comment: I don't see that in the Anniversary edition of Rise of the Runelords at all and can find no reference to it in the pfsrd.

Comment: @Rob Found (this)[http://www.obsidianportal.com/campaign/rotrllegacy/wikis/obtain-familiar] but no idea how valid it is.

Comment: @Mikalichov Thanks for the link, but not canon. The answer may well be "no"